# C# Winforms: BrightIdeasSoftware.fastObjectListView ButtonClick Event does not fire

Tags: c#, winforms, objectlistview

I have a FOLV on a form with a button column (`IsButton` property set to `true` and `ButtonSizing` set to `CellBounds`)

I have attached the event in the designer and can see this under Initialization.

```
this.fastObjectListView1.ButtonClick += new System.EventHandler
     <BrightIdeasSoftware.CellClickEventArgs>(this.fastObjectListView1_ButtonClick);
```

And in code behind: -

```
private void fastObjectListView1_ButtonClick(object sender, CellClickEventArgs e)
{
   Debug.Print("ButtonClick fired");
}
```

The event does not fire.

Are there other properties required? What could stop the `ButtonClick` event from firing?

Comment: Should work without additional steps. Maybe you changed some not so obvious setting that interferes with the column button functionality. You could try if you get it working with a "fresh" OLV. And make sure you do not have the columns disabled, that would prevent a button click.

Comment: Can you please show us a [mcve]? In other words, please give us all of the steps required to build a form with the two snippets of code you've shown, so that we can run that code and see the issue you're facing.

Comment: Please keep in mind that the code you've shown is like posting `int y = x * 2;` and saying "hey, when I run my code `y` is `8`, but I'm expecting `4`. What's wrong with my code?" So, of course, the issue is that `x` isn't what you expect it to be, but you haven't shown us where `x` is set. In your case, we need the full code to replicate the issue.